# Lualatex: landscape for some page (every page from metapost code)

Tags: luatex, landscape, metapost

I want to `landscape` some pages and keep other pages portrait. Each page is a picture from `metapost`. I compile in `lualatex`. Google tells me to use the package `lscape` or `pdflscape` for the purpose of landscape. The first code followed works. It landscapes the first page and keep the second page intact.

But, in my real situation - the second code, each picture is drawn from metapost code and it almost take one page and the second picture automatically goes to next page (no need of `\clearpage` and it seemed that `\clearpage` can't be included in metapost code). There are some globe variables defined at every beginning and they are used almost by every picture (page). So, there is only one `\begin{mplibcode} ... \end{mplibcode}` block that includes all metapost codes (all pages). How to landscape the first page?

This code can `landscape`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  % \everymplib{verbatimtex \leavevmode etex; beginfig(1);}
  % \everyendmplib{endfig;}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,tmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=0.5cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage[lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.6cm,tmargin=1.27cm,bmargin=2.27cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcommand{\defaultfontsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\begin{document}\defaultfontsize

\begin{landscape}
\begin{mplibcode}
  warningcheck := 0;
  input boxes
  input moi

  beginfig(1)
    draw origin -- (25cm,0);
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{landscape}

\clearpage

\begin{mplibcode}
  beginfig(2)
    % detail A - apex
    draw halfcircle scaled 2cm shifted (0, -50cm);
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

This is a frame of my real situation. How can I `landscape` the first page? As you can see, figure 1 is enclosed by `\begin{landscape}  \end{landscape}`. The code can't be compiled.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  % \everymplib{verbatimtex \leavevmode etex; beginfig(1);}
  % \everyendmplib{endfig;}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,tmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=0.5cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage[lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.6cm,tmargin=1.27cm,bmargin=2.27cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcommand{\defaultfontsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\begin{document}\defaultfontsize

\begin{mplibcode}
  warningcheck := 0;
  input boxes
  input moi

  % globe variables
  numeric d, b, tf, tw, r, scale;
  string section_name;

  section_name = "180PFC";
  d = 180;
  b = 75;
  tf = 11;
  tw = 6;
  r = 12;

\begin{landscape}
  beginfig(1)
    scale = 50;
    a very large picture from metapost
  endfig;
\end{landscape}

  beginfig(2)
    % detail A - apex
    scale := 5;
    another very large picture from metapost
    % draw origin -- (d, 0);
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `verbatimtex` blocks as explained on p.2 of [the manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib).   I have taken the liberty of simplifying the second (non-working) example above to show what can be done.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
% global variables
numeric d, scale;
d = 18;

verbatimtex \begin{landscape} etex
beginfig(1)
    scale := 10;
    % a very large picture from metapost
    draw fullcircle scaled d;
    currentpicture := currentpicture scaled scale;
endfig;

verbatimtex \end{landscape} etex
beginfig(2)
    scale := 5;
    % another very large picture from metapost
    draw origin -- (d, 0);
    currentpicture := currentpicture scaled scale;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

As the documentation explains, if you put TeX tokens in a `verbatimtex ... etex` block placed just before `beginfig()`, the tokens will be inserted just before the `hbox` emitted by the next `endfig` macro.  So in this use case, you get something like this for `lualatex` to process:

```
...
\begin{landscape}
<hbox produced by first endfig>
\end{landscape}
<hbox produced by second endfig>
...
```

and the output PDF looks like this:

[image]
which is (*I think*) what the OP wanted.

Comment: By the way, if the only reason you want to do this is to have global MP variables, it is probably easier (as of V2.9+) to use the `\mplibcodeinherit` option, so that each `mplibcode` environment sees previous definitions.

Comment: Glad to know the `\mplibcodeinherit{enable}`. Then I don't have to define global variable.